# Application Insights Saving javascript Trace

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure-application-insights

I'm using application insights for saving some errors data have attach some data, and one of the fields is the trace of the code (converted to string). My problem is sometimes the string is biggest that the 1024 chars permitted by aplication insights.

Error:
*Uncaught trackEvent failed, event will not be collected: [object String]"string value is too long. It has been truncated to 1024 characters.*

**[Edit]** Even there is no way to send more than 1024 chars, i wanna know if there a way to "get a compact trace of code" for not pass the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit cannot be overridden. There are checks both on the client side and server side and if event does not meet number of rules it is dropped.

Comment: My problem is not overwrite the limit. I wanna know if there a "compact way" to trace the code and send by application insights whithout pass the 1024 chars limit

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to split it and put in custom properties. Though it will not be very convenient to use and there still the limit on the total item size.

Comment: @AnastasiaBaranchenkova: Is the limit still active and does it apply to sql statements too logged by Status Monitor ?

Comment: I think yes. See code, it is open source: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/822036ddc8ee96b35c41659a8446d777d31b1321/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/Telemetry/Common/DataSanitizer.ts StatusMonitor does nothing but adding nuget packages to your redfield applications and install profiler. So yes, sanitation rules are the same.